# What is metaphysical contingency?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, ontology, necessity

I have always thought is something is metaphysically contingent is simply means that something, a state of affairs, MAY be the case.  Tomorrow I may stub my foot on a nail and feel pain. This happening is metaphysically contingent. It is not *a fortiori* possible.
However, I am reading (or attempting to) read a paper by  Braddon-Mitchel now, and he talks of "no-futurism", "eternalism" and all these other concepts in relation to metaphysical contingency, and, to be frank, I am confused!

Comment: Useful: [Varieties of Modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/).

Comment: See also [What exactly is metaphysical possibility?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/12610/what-exactly-is-metaphysical-possibility)

Comment: It sounds like you are conflating metaphysical contingency with some issues in the philosophy of time. They are related but not the same thing.

Comment: Presentism, eternalism, and the growing block theory (a synonym for no-futurism) are discussed in [this section](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/time/#PresEterGrowBlocTheo) of the SEP article on Time. As David Gudeman said, these questions are related to the ontology of time and are logically separate from the question of whether physical events are contingent or not.

Comment: Many thanks...a lot of these terms are pretty confusing at the outset (since they can easily be understand in so many ways)...it is like you have to really live with them for quite a while to internalize them.

Answer (score 2):

(a): the general intuition is as follows:

- contingent= there are worlds W1, W2 such that P holds in W1 but not in W2.
- possible = there is a world W1 where P holds.

this follows from a notion of necessity: in all worlds W, P holds. we thus obtain impossibility (no worlds in which P holds) and also possibility and contingency. In this straightforward sense, it is thus easy to move from contingency to possibility.

(b) if you like, you may easily move between talk of states of affairs obtaining and talk of propositions holding. also, theses definitions may be stated without possible worlds semantics.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. So, in terms of my example, "I may stub my foot on a nail and feel pain" (P)...insofar as this is metaphysically contingent, there is a W1 where this holds, but in world W2, this does not hold?  Apologies If I have misunderstood completely, I am still wrapping my head around this.  The notion of "metaphysical contingency" I have been carrying around in my head for years is quit simplistic (and the lecturer did not seem very clear on it himself).

Comment: @rux23 basically. most(?) philosophers will accept this as a rough characterization of contingency and possilbility. of course, there is disagreement on (a): the resources necessary for an adequate explanation of both and (b): the proper formalization for contingency (although its probably S5)